# SQL em script php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DsXML as Nvarchar(Max)),' xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"','') as xml).value('(/nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/transp/vol/qVol/node())[1]', 'int') as [qVol]
FROM SPDNFE
WHERE CdIdNFe = 'NFe13161203976141000132550030000435291400513027'
```

Ao por esta query SQL dentro de um script php, me retorna o seguinte erro.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'xmlns' (T_STRING)
```

Como está no PHP.

```
public function teste($teste) {
    $sql = 'SELECT
        CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DsXML as Nvarchar(Max)),' xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"','') as xml).value('(/nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/transp/vol/qVol/node())[1]', 'int') as [qVol]
        FROM SPDNFE
        WHERE CdIdNFe = '$teste'';
    $results = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            $info = new Model();
            $info->getQVol($row->qVol);
            $results[] = $info;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Já tentou tirar este espaço entre ' xmlns...'?

Comment: Já, mas faz parte do replace.

Comment: Teste dessa forma, por favor: `'SELECT
        CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DsXML as Nvarchar(Max)), " xmlns='http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'","") as xml).value("(/nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/transp/vol/qVol/node())[1]", "int") as [qVol]
        FROM SPDNFE
        WHERE CdIdNFe = "'.$teste.'"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o escapamento dos apóstrofos:

```
$sql = "SELECT
        CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DsXML as Nvarchar(Max)),' xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\"','') as xml).value('(/nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/transp/vol/qVol/node())[1]', 'int') as [qVol]
        FROM SPDNFE
        WHERE CdIdNFe = \'$teste\'";
```

@edit

Ao utilizar o apóstrofo para delimitar a sua `string`, o que você tentou fazer é interpretado da seguinte maneira e delimitada nas seguinte parte:

```
$sql =  'SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DsXML as Nvarchar(Max)),'
```

Você iniciou uma `string` com `'` e logo em seguida há uma ocorrência dum `'` onde não deveria significar o limite da `string`.

Como você quer que a `string` contenha o literal, você deve escapá-lo.

Veja um exemplo similiar onde ocorre o mesmo erro:

```
$string = 'Santa Bárbara D'Oeste';
```

Para que o literal `'` funcione corretamente na `string`, utilize `\` para escapar, ou uma função como [`addslashes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php):

```
$string = 'Santa Bárbara D\'Oeste';

$string = addslashes('Santa Bárbara D'Oeste');
```

Sugiro que dê uma lida sobre [`strings`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Tens como adicionar mais conteúdo sobre estes escapamentos ?

Comment: Mais conteúdo? Você deseja uma explicação sobre eles, é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo, se tiver como. Após por os apóstrofos me retornou outro erro. `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ARITHABORT'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.'`

Comment: Esse segundo erro já não tem qualquer relação com o primeiro, que consta na sua pergunta. Faça uma nova pergunta sobre a resolução desse segundo erro.

Comment: Fiz uma edição, verifique por favor. @Kevin.F

Comment: Perfeito, agora se conseguires me ajudar na outra pergunta está aqui o link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227367/erro-em-query-sql-no-php