# Erro em query SQL no PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Me deparei com um erro de sql, porém ao rodar a query no SQL Server Studio me retorna a consulta normal. Query que está abaixo.

```
SELECT
CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DsXML as Nvarchar(Max)),' xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"','') as xml).value('(/nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/transp/vol/qVol/node())[1]', 'int') as [qVol]
FROM SPDNFE
WHERE CdIdNFe = 'NFe13161203976141000132550030000435291400513027'
```

Já quando transporto a mesma query sql para o php me retorna um erro. 
Como está no php:

```
public function teste($nrchave) {
        $sql = "SELECT
            CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DsXML as Nvarchar(Max)),' xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\"','') as xml).value('(/nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/transp/vol/qVol/node())[1]', 'int') as [qVol]
            FROM SPDNFE
            WHERE CdIdNFe = '$nrchave'";
        $results = array();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt) {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $info = new Model();
                $info->setQVol($row->qVol);
                $results[] = $info;
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

Erro:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]SELECT failed
>   because the following SET options have incorrect settings:
>   'ARITHABORT'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed
>   views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes
>   and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial
>   index operations.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi adicionando o `SET ARITHABORT ON` em frente ao meu `SELECT`.

Ficando assim:

```
public function teste($nrchave) {
        $sql = "
            SET ARITHABORT ON
            SELECT
            CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DsXML as Nvarchar(Max)),' xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\"','') as xml).value('(/nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/transp/vol/qVol/node())[1]', 'int') as [qVol]
            FROM SPDNFE
            WHERE CdIdNFe = '$nrchave'";
        $results = array();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt) {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $info = new Model();
                $info->setQVol($row->qVol);
                $results[] = $info;
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }
```